# How to have 2 almost same packages together in workspace?

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm taking over my predecessor's job of ROS.
My predecessor gave me ROS codes as a ROS package.

I want to have in my workspace ***both of his original package and another package which I add changes to,
so that I can always execute them and compare their behavior difference***.

I tried the following procedure but got errors.

Let his original package be "original_package" and my working package be "my_package".

1. In ~/catkin_ws/src/, execute '**cp -r original_package my_package**'
2. In ~/catkin_ws/src/my_package/CMakeList.txt and package.xml, **replaced "original_package" with "my_package"**
3. In ~/cakin_ws/, execute 'catkin_make -B' (-B is just a option to build all things forcely)

But cakin said errors like below. Obviously this is due to **both 2 packages have the same-name modules.**

> CMake Error at
> my_package/CMakeLists.txt:134
> (add_executable):   add_executable
> cannot create target "module-name"
> ***because another target with   the same name already exists.  The
> existing target is an executable
> created   in source directory
> "~/cakin_ws/src/original_package".***
> See documentation   for policy CMP0002
> for more details.
>
> CMake Error at
> my_package/CMakeLists.txt:141
> (target_link_libraries):   Attempt to
> add link library
> "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/libroscpp.so" to
> target   "module-name" which is not
> built in this directory.

I really appreciate if you give me a solution !

**Versions Info: Ros Indigo & Ubuntu 14.04**

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243051/how-to-have-2-almost-same-packages-together-in-workspace?/) by [Nanoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27890/nanoha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2016-09-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-18**:
Wasn't this question already answered?

**Comment by [Nanoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27890/nanoha/) on 2016-09-18**:
Yes, Lucas's answer already solved my problem. I just forgot to close the question, it's my shame. Sorry, and thank you.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-19**:
No problem :) I thought I'd already seen this question answered some time ago (sort of like a deja-vu). I didn't mean to imply that you hadn't properly accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the name in your my_package CMakeLists.txt `add_executable()` or `add_library()` and `target_link_libraries()` to something different than what is in original_package.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2016-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nanoha](https://answers.ros.org/users/27890/nanoha/) on 2016-09-18**:
Thank you for answer, it might be too late to make a reply, but you answer soleved my problem. Thank you.